# Is it only the 'thoughts' of Gentiles that accuse and defend them in Romans 2:15?

Tags: romans, paul

It seems Paul only refers to the thoughts as accusing and defending Gentiles in the following text

Romans 2:15 New American Standard Bible (NASB)

> 15 in that they show the work of the Law written in their hearts, their conscience bearing witness and their ***thoughts*** alternately accusing or else defending them,

Does the accusing and defending only refer to 'thoughts' and not the conscience as well in the above text.

Does not the conscience also accuse and defend the Gentiles?

Comment: I am not sure what distinction you make - conscience is part of the human thought process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Romans 2:12-13,16 states the main message:

> For all who have sinned without the Law will also perish without the
>   Law, and all who have sinned under the Law will be judged by the
>   Law; for it is not the hearers of the Law who are just before God, but the
>   doers of the Law will be justified
>   ... on the day when, according to my gospel, God will judge the
>   secrets of men through Christ Jesus.

Romans 2:14-15 inserts a comment to clarify it:

> For when Gentiles who do not have
>   the Law do instinctively the things of the Law, these, not having the
>   Law, are a law to themselves,  in that they show the work of the Law
>   written in their hearts, their conscience bearing witness and their
>   thoughts alternately accusing or else defending them,

This comment says that even those that have never heard the law are capable of knowing right from wrong (e.g. most societies believe that murder is wrong) and of having a conscience that reminds them when they do wrong.  Their thoughts will react to their conscience either by rationalizing their behaviour or by admitting their fault.

The main message says that anyone without the Law will experience sin's death penalty, while those that know the Law will be judged by the Law based on their thoughts.

The same thought process that those without the Law experience also happens with Christians.  Their conscience lets them know when they have broken the Law, and they will either rationalize or repent in their thoughts.  Simply knowing the Law isn't enough, one has to live a life that follows the law as well.   They are aware of God's Law, and so Jesus will judge them based on their secret thoughts, their inner reaction to what they *know* is right or wrong.  Did they accept that they had done wrong or did they try to explain away what happened?

**Is it only the 'thoughts' of Gentiles that accuse and defend them?**

Yes.  The CSB translation perhaps captures it best (v15):

> Their consciences confirm this. Their competing thoughts either accuse or
>   even excuse them